# How to Make Selenium Locator Unique OR Inner HTML Unique

Tags: python, selenium

A simple need: How to modify the HTML Source so that every innerhtml for a particular HTML element is unique. A simple example could explain the same more clearly:

```
<html>
<a href="/hello/doit.do"><img src="Button.bmp" border="0"></a>
<a href="/hello/doit.do">A Real Link</a>
</html>
```

If you notice, the user will see it as a text-link and image-link. If I wish to find this element using attributes only by building a CSS locator like this:

```
loc = 'css=a[href="/hello/doit.do"]'
```

Selenium will find two elements.
Using Selenium RC Client in Python 2.7, I wish to simply add an random number as ID attribute so as to separate them. My question is, how do I loop through all the common innerHTML and add a random number?

As far as I know,

```
get_css_count(loc)
```

will only get you number = 2. What I need is the inner HTML of each of those in order to insert a unique attribute?

Long story short, selenium has `get_attribute(attributeLocator)`, I want to know if there is a `set_attribute(attributeLocator, value)`?

Comment: You could change the html by executing some JS. Would use xpath

Comment: Could you please be more specific as to "some JS"? And why can't I use css?

Comment: Use xpath selectors instead of css ones:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764856/selenium-css-locator-all-attribute-options-with-and-without-being-strict/8772313#8772313

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to modify DOM using Selenium? You could change DOM using page js as @racar suggested (e.g. for jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    var i = 1;
    $('a[href="/hello/doit.do"]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('id', 'link_' + i);
        i += 1;
    });
});
```

That will add IDs "link_1", "link_2", ... for all your links.

Or you could add that IDs when you render HTML, if you render it yourself. May be if you share your real task, why you need to separate that links, we could suggest a better solution.

Comment: "you could add that IDs when you render HTML" Why didn't I think of that? Awesome... Thanks!!

Any case this the real deal for me:
So, let me explain you 1st in detail what I am trying to achieve so that you can suggest me a better way. There is a webpage which has all the HTML elements like: mayukhbose.com/elements.html Cont... in next comment

Comment: Continued here... What I wish to do is, from Python make simple methods/functions that can automate interactions with the HTML elements. For e.g: click_button(button_name='Send Data'). I can easily write these methods using Selenium's Python Client. However, the Selenium's Python Client only takes element locators as parameters. Now, I need to somehow create these locators based on the text found on the webpage. This can be done by parsing the webpage (where BeautifulSoup is really useful). I hope you get my idea. thanks, Amit

Comment: Do you generate that html page? If so, then adding unique parameters like id would be the best solution I think, then selectors will be small and clear and there will be no ambiguity (one selector matches many elements). But you also could find text in XPath selectors, using `contains()` function: `//a[contains(text(), 'Some case-sensitive text')]` or `//a[contains(., 'Another text)]`. There are [many other functions](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp) you could use.

Comment: Think of it this way.... There is a method called click_button(button_name). I want this to work with any webpage (be in mine, or google, or yahoo, etc.) Using Selenium/Javascript, I can always embed dynamic IDs into the webpages. Thats what I am doing now and it works like a charm. Thanks for the help