# Selenium CSS Locator All Attribute Options with and without being strict

Tags: python, selenium

I need your help again.
So, this is regarding the Selenium CSS Locator that I am building based on what I see in the innerHTML. My question is simple: What are the allowed attributes that can go in CSS locator and how to make it strict?

For example, for HTML

```
<input id="tbd" type="text" disabled="disabled">
<input type="submit" id="b1" value="b11" onclick="javascript: alert('button1')">
```

For the above HTML, CSS can easily be built respectively:

```
css=input[id="tbd"][type="text"][disabled="disabled"]
css=input[id="b1"][value="b11"][onclick="javascript:alert('button1')"]
```

As I found out that, onclick and disabled are not supported as attributes. So, there you go!! How do I know which locatorType to choose?

My 2nd question, I wish to be really strict in finding out the locator.
For example,
I wish this locator

```
css=input[name="tbd"][type="text"]
```

to match this HTML

```
<input name="tbd" type="text">
```

and not this

```
<input name="tbd" type="text" disabled="disabled">
```

This is what I mean by being strict.

Any help?

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: id tags should be unique in the html document.(http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp)

Comment: Fixed the question!! But I still don't know the answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

For disabled elements there is [disabled pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#enableddisabled):

```
css=input:disabled[id="tbd"][type="text"]
```

From [that document](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) seems you really can't select by onclick and other events (which is logical, css is responsible for representation, not for js events). Why not use XPath for that?

Your last question could be rewritten as follows I suppose:

`css=input[type="text"]` to match this HTML `<input type="text">` and not this `<input type="text" disabled="disabled">`

AFAIK there is no such "strict" matching. You need to specify full selector that will match only needed elements: `css=input:enabled[type="text"]` or `css=input:not(:disabled)[type="text"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) for complex selectors, it will save you a lot of time and code.

This is an example of xpath selectors usage, but using different library for brevity
(`BY_ID_XPATH` and `BY_ID_AND_NOT_DISABLED_XPATH` xpath expressions will be the same for your selenium code):

```
from lxml import etree

HTML = """
<input id="tbd" type="text" disabled="disabled">
<input id="tbd" type="text">
"""

BY_ID_XPATH = '//input[@id="tbd"]'
BY_ID_AND_NOT_DISABLED_XPATH = '//input[@id="tbd" and not(@disabled)]'

elements_tree = etree.fromstring(HTML, parser=etree.HTMLParser())

elements_tree.xpath(BY_ID_XPATH)
# matches 2 elements: [<Element input at 102ea1d08>, <Element input at 102ea1db8>]

elements_tree.xpath(BY_ID_AND_NOT_DISABLED_XPATH)
# matches 1 element:  [<Element input at 102ea1d08>]
```

`id` attribute should be unique across the whole web page. However this is not always the  case, since nothing can stop developer to use more than one identical `id` value.

If you have any power in the project – you can use `id` as unique attribute to keep automation code short and clean, and file bugs like "Duplicated id attribute on the Home page".

For `onclick` matching your selector will look like this:

```
BY_ONCLICK_XPATH = """//input[@onclick="javascript:alert('button1')"]"""
```

Comment: Xpath is slow, and thats why I am not using it. But thanks a lot for the xpath knowledge